# How to add a winforms usercontrol in an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, winforms, c#-3.0

How can we add a winforms user control in an aspx page?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What control do you want to host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at an article from ASP.NET.4guysFrom - [Hosting a Windows Control in a Web Form](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619191631/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx) and also [Hosting .NET Windows Forms Controls in IE](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030610.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as far as I'm aware. If you want a native client style experience in a web app (and AJAX isn't good enough for you), you should look at using SilverLight.

Comment: When using IE and .Net (at least at the time of .NET 1.0) you could use a WinForm control in the same way as a ActiveX control.  Not many people did due to the small number of users that had .net installed.

Answer (score 0):

its possible to embebed but user will need to download the assembly and executed locally

http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/09/19/hosting-a-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page.aspx